# Maximizing number of parallel operation in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda which has to invoke an API endpoint for 2 million records. Considering that the maximum execution period of Lambda is 15 minutes. I have to somehow process all these records using one Lambda(that is in 15 minutes if possible). The API endpoint which I want to invoke can handle the TPS of 3000. I want to maximize/parallelize my calls so I can utilize the TPS provided and run the operations using a single Lambda. I have created my invocations within parallelStream in Java. Is is possible to do it using the current approach? If yes, What changes would I have to make in Lambda Runtime in order to use multi core?

Comment: Is this a single job or you plan to repeat it again and again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Considering that the maximum execution period of Lambda is 15 minutes.
> I have to somehow process all these records using one Lambda(that is
> in 15 minutes if possible).

Why? This defeats the entire reason you would use AWS Lambda for this task. Why limit yourself to a single Lambda function invocation to do all this work?

If you wrote a script to take your 2 million records and add them to an SQS queue, then you could have the AWS Lambda service automatically feed these records into multiple, parallel instances of your AWS Lambda function. This would allow you to easily tune the number of Lambda functions you want to have running in parallel, and also automatically handle retries in the case of failures.

Comment: Do you mean, Write a lambda to feed these records into an SQS and trigger another Lambda(one which calls API) on the SQS event. This way Multiple Lambdas would be spawned reacting to SQS events. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Although I'm not sure the initial thing should be a Lambda function, or just a script running on an EC2 server or your local laptop or something. It depends on where the database server is, and how long it takes to send those records to SQS.

Comment: Alright, got it. Do I need to configure this multiple Async Lambda Spawning behaviour on the console or is it inherently build into AWS runtime?

Comment: By default I think it will scale up to 1000 parallel executions to handle your SQS messages. You may want to tune that based on the endpoint you are hitting.